# Make deletes my target. Why?

Tags: shell, makefile

From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html#Chained-Rules):

> The second difference is that if `make` **does create B** in order to
>   update something else, it deletes B later on after it is no longer
>   needed.  Therefore, an intermediate file **which did not exist before**
>   `make` also does not exist after `make`.  `make` reports the deletion to
>   you by printing a `rm -f` command showing which file it is deleting.

Now, a makefile, like this:

```make
$(shell rm -rf x D)
$(shell mkdir D)
$(shell touch D/x)

VPATH = D

all: x ;

x:: phony
    @echo '$@'

.INTERMEDIATE: D/x

.PHONY: phony
```

Running:

```console
$ make
D/x
rm D/x

$ ls D/x
ls: cannot access D/x: No such file or directory
```

Now, given the above quote, that Make removes only an "intermediate file which did not exist before", we have here a clear case, where:

1. The target **did exist** before running Make.
2. Make **did not** create the target.

Still, Make feels that it is appropriate to delete this file. A thing that it was **not** asked to do. So why does it?

Compare it to the following simple makefile:

```make
$(shell rm -rf x)
$(shell touch x)

x ::
    @echo '$@'

.INTERMEDIATE: x
```

Running:

```console
$ make
x

$ ls x
x
```

Simple as that! Make did not remove a file that:

1. It did not create!
2. Existed, before running Make

Because, the all point of intermediate files removal is, to quote the documentation above:

> Therefore, an intermediate file which did not exist before `make` also does not exist after `make`.

Nothing else!

So, how come in the first example, does Make go-around and deletes **pre-existing** files?

Answer (score 1):

#### Description of Execution

In your first example whilst `D/x` did exist before executing `make` because you have specified `phony` as a prerequisite `make` must remake `D/x` as the target `phony` does not exist. So `make` created the *intermediate* file `D/x` and according to your quote it

> **deletes** `D/x` when it is no longer needed.

after having remade `all`. The path of execution `make` takes is

- `all` does not exist, so we must check `x`
- `make` finds `D/x` but `phony` does not exist
- `make` remakes `phony` and now we must remake `D/x` as it depends on `phony` which has been updated
- `make` remakes the **intermediate** file `D/x` *(which we must now delete when it is no longer needed)*
- `make` can now create `all`, and finally
- `make` deletes the **intermediate** file `D/x`

#### Relation to Documentation

The key part of the documentation you have quoted is the first sentence.

> The second difference is that if `make` **does create** `B` in order to update something else, it **deletes** `B` later on after it is no longer needed.

This is exactly what happens in your example. `make` creates `D/x` and so it must delete `D/x` later on when it is not needed.

#### Explanation of Documentation Interpretation

I think you need to be a little careful of your interpretation of the documentation. By stating *'Therefore'* they are **not** saying `make` will **not** delete a file that already existed. They are simply saying as a consequence of `make` updating an intermediate file which did not previously exist it will delete it when it is finished. They are **still** leaving the **possibility** that an intermediate file **existed before** `make` was executed that it **had to update** and **subsequently deletes**.

---

I think I should stress this a bit more. Given the quote

> Therefore, an intermediate file which did not exist before `make` also does not exist after `make`.

this does not mean `make` wont delete files that existed beforehand.

Comment: The very proof that Make does not delete a pre-existing file, is my second example.
where:

    1)  Make had to remade `x`.
    2)  `x` existed before running Make.
    3)  Make "re-builds" the target by running some command.
    4)  Make did **not** delete the target, as it did not create it, to begin with.

Comment: Go ahead, and modify the second example above, so that `x` is a dependency of some target `all`. Same results.